# What do you call someone who does a favor for you?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word, something like "good samaritan" but more specific; someone who does a favor for you but not necessarily an acquaintance.  I.e. I asked for a hand moving my couch and a ______ gave me a hand.

Comment: Ethiopian has a word for this: balewiletayē. It means someone who's done a favor for you.

Answer (score 2):

A **benefactor** is someone who has helped you in some way, so it fits pretty well.

In the sentence you gave, there's enough context that just **bystander**, **onlooker**, or even **fellow** would work.

Comment: I suggest supplying this answer with links to one or more online dictionary definitions, and possibly a link to a [list of synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/benefactor) to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

**[Altruist](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/altruist)**

"A person unselfishly concerned for or devoted to the welfare of others (opposed to egoist )." ~ Dictionary.com

**[Philanthropist](https://www.wordnik.com/words/philanthropist)**

"One who is actuated by a philanthropic spirit; one who loves mankind, or wishes well to his fellow-men and endeavors to benefit them by active works of benevolence or beneficence; one who from philanthropic motives endeavors to do good to his fellows." ~ Century Dictionary and Cyclopedia (1890-1914)